# FCoE on RedHat 7.4 server with QLogic BCM57xx not detecting the SAN

Tags: redhat, iscsi, broadcom

I am trying to configure RH7.4, installed a Dell Poweredge FC830 to talk to an EMC Unity SAN. The server has a QLogic BCM57xx card. I used the lifecycle controller to deploy the OS. After the installation I couldn't see the expected 'Fibre' lines in the lspci output. What I can see is:

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Limited BCM57840 NetXtreme II Ethernet Multi Function (rev 11)
01:00.1 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Limited BCM57840 NetXtreme II Ethernet Multi Function (rev 11)
01:00.2 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Limited BCM57840 NetXtreme II Ethernet Multi Function (rev 11)
01:00.3 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Limited BCM57840 NetXtreme II Ethernet Multi Function (rev 11)
01:00.4 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Limited BCM57840 NetXtreme II Ethernet Multi Function (rev 11)
01:00.5 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Limited BCM57840 NetXtreme II Ethernet Multi Function (rev 11)
01:00.6 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Limited BCM57840 NetXtreme II Ethernet Multi Function (rev 11)
01:00.7 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Limited BCM57840 NetXtreme II Ethernet Multi Function (rev 11)
```

There is two NICs with four ports. Ports are partitioned. Two partitions per port.  For the first two ports, partition one is a Ethernet IF and partition two is a FCoE interface.
The server was zoned with a Windows OS disk. The initiators on the SAN(EMC Unity 500) were visible. After installing RedHat the SAN is moaning that its lost the connection to the initiators. Although I ran the scsi-rescan script I cannot see the SAN from the server. I installed the qla2xxx module and loaded it.

```
 lsmod | grep fc
scsi_transport_fc      64007  1 qla2xxx
scsi_tgt               20027  1 scsi_transport_fc
```

Still cannot see the SAN and vice versa.
I am clueless and don't know on how to continue from here. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You'll have more luck if you ask this question on serverfault.com.  This site is dedicated to programming topics.